# Plone folder ordering: no draggingHook

Tags: plone

I support about a dozen Plone sites, all running some version of Plone 4.2, and only on one do I have this problem. This particular site is running Plone 4.2.6 (4212).

When displaying **.../folder_contents**, for any folder, each member object has only the up/down arrows for folder ordering, not the draggingHook.

IF I turn on ***Development mode*** in **portal_javascripts/manage_jsForm**, everything displays correctly, but I hardly want to do this on a continuous basis.  I've tried making every javascript file not Mergable and I've tried setting Compression to None (independently -- I haven't done them both together, yet). Neither of those work.

So, my actual question is which script is responsible for setting the *draggingHook* class? grepping my entire eggs directory shows only plone.app.kss, but that's not part of portal_javascripts, which leaves me wondering how setting Development mode can make a difference.

jsregistry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_javascripts" meta_type="JavaScripts Registry">
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquery.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="jquery-integration.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="False"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.validator.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="False"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.rangeinput.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.dateinput.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="False"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.plugins.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.overlayhelpers.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.form.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="register_function.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="plone_javascript_variables.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="modernizr.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="nodeutilities.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="cookie_functions.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="full" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="livesearch.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++search.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="select_all.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="dragdropreorder.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="mark_special_links.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="full" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="collapsiblesections.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="collapsibleformfields.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression=""
    id="++resource++plone.app.discussion.javascripts/comments.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="form_tabbing.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="popupforms.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="first_input_focus.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="full" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="accessibility.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="jquery.highlightsearchterms.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="styleswitcher.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="toc.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="dropdown.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="table_sorter.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="calendar_formfield.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="formUnload.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="formsubmithelpers.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="unlockOnFormUnload.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="jquery.tinymce.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="True" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="tiny_mce_gzip.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="python:not context.restrictedTraverse('@@plone_portal_state').anonymous() or (getattr(portal, 'kupu_library_tool', None) and portal.kupu_library_tool.isKupuEnabled(REQUEST=request))"
    id="sarissa.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="python: not here.restrictedTraverse('@@plone_portal_state').anonymous() and here.restrictedTraverse('@@kss_devel_mode').ison()"
    id="++resource++kukit.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="none" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="False"
    expression="python: not here.restrictedTraverse('@@plone_portal_state').anonymous() and here.restrictedTraverse('@@kss_devel_mode').ison()"
    id="++resource++kukit-devel.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++dropdown-menu.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++vPIP/vpip.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++vPIP/vpipit.js" inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++flowplayer-html/flowplayer-3.2.2.min.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="++resource++collective.js.moment/moment.js"
    inline="False"/>
 <javascript authenticated="False" bundle="default" cacheable="True"
    compression="safe" conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True"
    expression="" id="collective.js.jqueryui.custom.min.js" inline="False"/>
</object>
```

Comment: But when you keep the portal_javascript tool in production mode you are getting any JavaScript error?

Comment: No, I haven't seen any errors! I'm running in Chrome and Firefox with all debugging options available, and nothing shows up.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea :-\

Comment: Do you have the kukit-devlel.js enabled? I remember a long time ago I experienced some problems with this js (It's the kss dev js. You should disable this on a prod environment)

Comment: Development mode can make a difference, For example js comments with /* Comment */ could lead you to problem if the compression type is "safe".

Comment: Is upgrading to Plone 4.3.2 an option? kss is removed in this Version, so dnd in folder contents is no implemented with kss.

Comment: Check https://github.com/plone/plone.app.kss/blob/master/plone/app/kss/plugins/plone/plugin.js#L205 I guess that's the place, where kss hides the dnd functionality for folder_contents :-)

Comment: Could be that former KSS interferes, yet, just be sure it doesn't get dropped: the actual script resonsible is `portal_skins/plone_ecmascript/dragdropreorder.js`. I have some more quests: 1.) Are there other sites the same ZOPE-instance, is dragndrop working there and if yes, can you see any difference between them? 2.) Was there a Plone-upgrade done lately? 3.) Any add-ons involved? 4.) Could you please export and paste the `jsregistry.xml` (also for possibly reproducing the issue)?

Comment: @Mathias I _did_ at the time I opened this question have kukit-devel.js enabled, but I had disabled it by the time you responded, and it makes no difference.

I also had tried turning off development mode and turning off compression on all script files (as mentioned above), so "safe" compression isn't the issue.

Comment: @Ida Ebkes No, dragdropreorder.js is NOT responsible. It handles the actual dragging, but the problem is that the drag handle never replaces the up/down arrows, so dragdropreorder.js doesn't know it can operate on these elements. And, yes, there are half a dozen other sites, none of which have this problem. Of course there are add-ons involved :-) I'm certain that the problem is with one of them doing something that interferes, but I can't see which... I've exported and compared the jsregistry, often.  I'll add it here shortly.

Comment: @Mathias Yes, upgrading to 4.3.2 _is_ an option, so maybe I should try that. I knew that plone.app.kss was involved here, but it doesn't help me to know exactly where if that doesn't explain how turning on development mode affects it. otoh, if I can just remove kss altogether, maybe I don't care!

Comment: Yes, dragdopreorder.js IS responsible, it does apply the `draggingHook`-class, that's what you were asking for. KSS shouldn't be part of the prob, imho.

Comment: @IdaEbkes Sorry, but no. There is _no_ occurrence of that class name in dragdropreorder.js _prior_ to 4.3.x.  KSS is absolutely part of the problem in 4.2, which is what the question is about. The fact that dragdropreorder.js does set the draggingHook class in 4.3 makes Mathias suggestion more tempting.  Getting 4.3 to install on my systems has been more troublesome than I'd hoped, though.

Comment: @Mathias Well, 4.3 is in and takes care of the problem and despite taking me pretty much a day to get various products working properly with it, was really less hassle than I've had in more than a year of this drag & drop not working properly. Post an actual "answer" instead of a comment to claim the bounty.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my mistake, I hastely grabbed a 4.3-instance, when rechecking. Anyway, if you could find differences to the other site of the same instance, I'd still be interested for sharing more details, just for curiousity.

Comment: Moving a DB from P-4.1.6 to P-4.2.6, then looking at folder_contents, the error you described shows up (arrows, no dragbuttons) and dissapears when *only* executing the upgrade for p.a.jquery via portal_setup. P-4.1.6 pins p.a.jquery to 1.3.2 and P-4.2.6 pins it to 1.4.4, so I wanted to see what has changed and Alas, no history/repo/pypi-release available for versions older than 1.4.4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade your plone site to Plone 4.3.2 (in the meantime Plone 4.3.3).
In Plone 4.3 they removed kss and replaced it by some pieces of jQuery based js.

So also the D'n'D feature on folder_contents is not longer implemented with kss.

I've experienced similar problems with Plone 4.2.x and an upgrade to Plone 4.3 solved this issue.